# Office 365 Rest api auth

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, office365

I'm trying to use the Office 365 api to fetch user's calendar events. I managed to get a valid oauth2 access_token, but when I use the api, the authentication fails.

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars
Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer **MYACCESSTOKEN**
```

A very slow response (about 5 secs) give me a 401 Unauthorized...I have already checked that my access_token is not expired.

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 10:53:12 GMT
Request-Id: d2a72db7-0e72-4ef4-8579-97453a28656b
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: ClientId=BWUSNGYUIVTW9QOSG; expires=Fri, 06-Nov-2015 10:53:08 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, exchangecookie=723dca46630646a2bc80b4668dd113d7; expires=Fri, 06-Nov-2015 10:53:13 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, X-BackEndCookie2=5a7ff0a2-22c1-4d5b-b280-6af6689779a7=u56Lnp2ejJqBxpqdxs3IzczSmpzHzdLLnc7P0p7Gx5nSyMrGm5ydzMyencbKgZKejZOWmo3RkJGSlpyNkIyQmYvRnJCSgc3PzsvSzs3Sz8mrzs/FyszFzsyBmoqNj42bz87Rj42Qm9Gah5yXnpGYmpOenYzRnJCS; expires=Sat, 06-Dec-2014 10:53:13 GMT; path=/api; secure; HttpOnly, X-BackEndCookie=5a7ff0a2-22c1-4d5b-b280-6af6689779a7=u56Lnp2ejJqBxpqdxs3IzczSmpzHzdLLnc7P0p7Gx5nSyMrGm5ydzMyencbKgZKejZOWmo3RkJGSlpyNkIyQmYvRnJCSgc3PzsvSzs3Sz8mrzs/FyszFzsw=; expires=Sat, 06-Dec-2014 10:53:13 GMT; path=/api; secure; HttpOnly
Www-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Beserver: AMSPR01MB103
X-Calculatedbetarget: amspr01mb103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
X-Diaginfo: AMSPR01MB103
X-Feserver: BLUPR07CA059
X-Ms-Diagnostics: 2000001;reason="The audience claim value is invalid '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.";error_category="invalid_token"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi Nico, Thanks for reporting the issue!  Can you please update your question with the headers you received in the response?  This will help us investigate why auth is failing for your request.  Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question.  The 30s delay with some requests is a known issue and we are already working on a fix to address this.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Ok :) Thx for the answer. Where should I look to be noticed when the issue will be fixed ? Is it supposed to be fixed in the next days / weeks / months ?

Comment: It is being fixed right now, and will be available in a few weeks time.  Thanks for your patience.  Venkat

Comment: Venkat, any update on when this should get fixed ? I still got very very slow responses...Thx

Comment: We have already rolled out one fix and our measurements show improvements. And more are on the way.  Can you please share the specific request where you are seeing issues?  Is it sporadic delays with any type of request, or consistent delay with a specific request?

Comment: /calendarview on 3 weeks always takes more than 5s, very often more than 10s, on all the users I have

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally managed to get a 200. My problem was the resource param when asking a token  was set by defaut to 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 (I'm using Rails omniauth-azure-oauth2 gem).

I changed it to https://outlook.office365.com and it works.

Still, the api give me the right answers, but the call is ultra-slow (up to 30s !). Any clue on how to make it respond in a reasonable time ?