# Restricting Azure Identity Providers

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth

I have set up authentication for my application using the Azure Rest API / OAuth 2 flow, following the steps outlined here:

https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/azure-rest-api-with-oauth2/

I have created an ActiveDirectory application within Azure which is linked to an ActiveDirectory instance.

Inside my own application I have configured it to post to the following Azure OAuth endpoint:

```
https://login.windows.net/<<MY-AD-TENANT-ID>>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<<GUID>>&response_type=code
```

This all works fine. I can authenticate against my ActiveDirectory using emails of the form

```
someuser@<myDomain>.com
```

However, I have realised that I can also authenticate using any valid microsoft email address, which obviously means that anyone with a valid microsoft email can get an access token for my application e.g.

```
randomUser@hotmail.com
```

Can anyone tell me how I can restrict the authentication to just allow users who are in my Active directory? Users with emails of the form

```
someuser@<myDomain>.com
```

I have looked through the documentation but have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Ebert's prompt I've figured out a way to solve my problem. I don't know if it will help anyone else, but...

Basically when my app gets the token from Azure, before passing it on to the client, I can decode the JWT and just look at the `email` field.

In my case if the email address isn't one that belongs to my domain I can just send a 401 unauthorized back to the client.

It feels weird that Azure doesn't offer some way of doing this via config, maybe it does, but noone has answered this for me, and I've read enough of their docs now to want to pull my own eyes out so I never see the word `Azure` again...

Answer (score 1):

**Mechanics of Token Validation**

What does that really mean: *to validate a token*? It boils down to three things, really:

1. Verify that it is well-formed
2. Verify that it is coming from the intended authority
3. Verify that it is meant for the current application

Your problem is that you are not doing the number 3 validation.

You probably are missing something like this in your application where you are validating the token:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have a couple of questions 1) I'm using Scala to write all this, and I haven't used a pre-existing library for the OAuth, i've just implemented it all myself, so could you tell me what library this code snippet is from? (Is it C#?)   2) I perhaps naively assumed that I wouldn't have to check the token I receive from Azure, but can I assume from your answer that there's no way to remove microsoft / hotmail email address from the valid identity providers by configuration in Azure, and that I have to do verification myself in my code?

Comment: 1. it is C# and from OWIN/Katana library. 2. Yes you will have to validate it on the server side to see if it is a legit token.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have the same problem and trying to figure out a solution.
That's what I found out:

After authentication you get back a JSON Web Token (see this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx). After decoding this, there are several information available. But I am not sure which of those could possibly make sure to only allow login of the specified Active Directory.

@Aram refers to the values **audience** (`aud`) and **tenant** (`tid`). Unfortunately audience is always set to the app_id given with the request and tenant is always set to the tenant-id of the Azure tenant, although you are using a live.com account, for example.

Finally, I came up with the idea of checking for the existence of `oid` (»Object identifier (ID) of the user object in Azure AD.«, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx). I hope that this one will only be set if the user is part of the Active Directory that is issuing the authorization.

As a result, I set my app up to do the following: If in the decoded version of the `id_token` of the *Access token response* there is no `oid` property set – the login-request will be rejected.

**Problem is: I can't confirm that my approach works, because I don't have a second Azure AD and can't check if only live/hotmail/... users will not be given a `oid`, but also users from different ADs.** Maybe @bobbyr you could try that out and report?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks. It's good to know it's not just me struggling with this :)  Can you tell me how you are decoding the JWT?

Comment: Ok, ignore that last question about decoding. I see that there's a standardized method for decoding JWT tokens

Comment: @bobbyr Referring to your answer: That sounds like a good second option if the `oid` approach turns out bad. Thanks! In general, there are some weird »bugs« about Azure OAuth/REST API that are absolutely missing in the multiple extensive documentations or blogposts by Microsoft. (this issue and e.g. the _resource_ thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762441/office-365-rest-api-auth/.)